# How to not select and submit the hovered suggestion in MaterialUI <Autocomplete /> when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, material-ui, autocomplete

I've created an [example GitHub repository](https://github.com/cideM/autocomplete_question) that demonstrates the unwanted behavior. The `README` contains instructions, but I'll repeat them here. You need NodeJS and Yarn.

Clone the repository, then run `yarn install` followed by `yarn dev`. You can now open a website in your local browser at `http://localhost:5173/`.

1. Click on the input field, the suggestions should pop up at the
2. Hover the mouse over "Pulp Fiction", or any other suggestion
3. Hit enter
4. You should now see what was "submitted", which is the suggestion you hovered over

I want to only submit the following values:

- Select a suggestion and press enter
- Click a suggestion
- Type in the input field, press enter

In other words, never submit a suggestion that was only hovered over. All other default behavior of the component should be preserved.